# How to change the niceness of openvpn on debian?

Tags: linux, debian, openvpn, systemd

I am currently using debian 8.2 with systemd.

```
$ cat /etc/default/openvpn
...
# WARNING: If you're running systemd the rest of the
# options in this file are ignored.
...
# Optional arguments to openvpn's command line
OPTARGS="--nice -20"
#
```

It seems that this option does not work with systemd.
Are there anyway to change the niceness at the start of the openvpn service ?

Comment: Did you take a look at the OpenVPN unit? There could be a settings file somewhere. I'll look into it later.

Comment: You can put the `nice -20` also put into the server's config file (without the `--`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under systemd a whole new way of managing system resources exists: `cgroups`. Every service is assigned to a `cgroup`, and every `cgroup` is controlled thru three main controllers, `cpu`, `memory` and `blkio`.

In  your case, you may decrease the amount of CPU the `openvpn` service receives by decreasing its *CPUshares*. By default, every process receives 1024 CPUshares. If you want to decrease that, say to  800 shares, you create an *ad hoc* file `/etc/systemd/system/openvpn.service` which overrides the package-supplied one in `/lib/systemd/system`, with the following content:

```
.include /lib/systemd/system/openvpn.service

[Service]
CPUShares=800
```

The first line reads-in the package-supplied service, the remaining two lines decrease the amount of CPU allocated to the service. Restart the service,

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart openvpn.service
```

you are done.

You can find an intro to `cgroups` [on PID EINS](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/resources.html), and [on the ever helpful Arch Linux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cgroups).

Comment: [Wrong service.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206490/5132)

Comment: Weird. I wonder how this relates to processes that are not services... lets say process 1 is a service and process 2 is not. Both have the same nice level and both want 100% of the cpu.  Under normal circumstances they would both get 50% of the CPU. Now does lowering CPUShares of process 1 result in process 1 getting less than 50% cpu?

Comment: @Daps0l Yes it does, because at this point the two hold different amounts of  shares of the CPU. You can also change the CPUShares of a non-service process, to know more you may read the Arch Wiki reference above.